# Efficiently ordering by the number of matched columns in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, similarity

I have a denormalized table where each column is a tag associated with an object. E.g. this post could have the tags "postgres", "indexing", and "similarity". The table looks something like:

```
| id | col1     | col2     | col3       |
| 1  | postgres | indexing | similarity |
| 2  | postgres | foo      | bar        |
| 3  | foo      | bar      | baz        |
```

If I wanted to find the post most similar to this one, I could do something like:

```
select *
from mytable
order by (col1 = 'postgres' or col2 = 'postgres' or col3 = 'postgres')::int
  + (col1 = 'indexing' or col2 = 'indexing' or col3 = 'indexing')::int
  + (col1 = 'similarity' or col2 = 'similarity' or col3 = 'similarity')::int desc
limit 10;
```

However, as far as I know, this can't use any indexes for sorting; it has to do a table scan. When I ran it on a similar table with every column indexed, I got this:

```
Limit  (cost=35124.06..35125.23 rows=10 width=21) (actual time=204.323..206.350 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=35124.06..132353.15 rows=833334 width=21) (actual time=204.322..206.344 rows=10 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=34124.04..35165.70 rows=416667 width=21) (actual time=194.794..194.795 rows=10 loops=3)
              Sort Key: ((((((col1 = 'aa'::text) OR (col2 = 'aa'::text) OR (col3 = 'aa'::text)))::integer + (((col1 = 'bb'::text) OR (col2 = 'bb'::text) OR (col3 = 'bb'::text)))::integer) + (((col1 = 'cc'::text) OR (col2 = 'cc'::text) OR (col3 = 'cc'::text)))::integer)) DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "__testTags__"  (cost=0.00..25120.01 rows=416667 width=21) (actual time=0.016..145.436 rows=333333 loops=3)
Planning Time: 0.139 ms
Execution Time: 206.371 ms
```

Is there a way to order by the number of matching columns more efficiently? I looked into using a vector embedding, but Postgres doesn't have any good vector or nearest-neighbor support. Also, fulltext search doesn't seem to support ranking by the number of matches.

The only solution I can think of is doing 4 separate queries: get rows with 3 matches, then rows with 2 matches, then rows with 1 match, then rows with no matches. This is much faster than the query above. However, if I want to add more columns, the query will get really complicated.

Comment: Databases were never intended to do this kind of fuzzy matching. You could try to move to an EAV schema though ... [which would result in the query just being a COUNT()]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use an index for your purpose which relies on an array type :

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS col_index ON mytable USING gin ((array[col1,col2,col3]) array_ops) ;
```

Then, the following query can use the index `col_index` for filtering the rows where one or several colomns match the search criteria and then calculate the number of exact matching :

```
SELECT m.match_count, t.*
  FROM mytable AS t
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     ( SELECT count(*) AS match_count
         FROM unnest(array['postgres', 'indexing', 'similarity']) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(arr, id)
        WHERE (array[t.col1, t.col2, t.col3])[a.id] = a.arr
     ) AS m
 WHERE array[t.col1, t.col2, t.col3] && array['postgres', 'indexing', 'similarity']
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f61117200840b84efb04e0a3aa58bb17).

Comment: This. I would even recommend storing the tags in an array in the first place, not denormalised in arbitrary columns.

Comment: So this only finds rows where the first array element matches the first column, and so on?

Comment: This exactly finds rows where at least one array elements matches one column. `match_count` may be zero when the array element doesn't match the right column, for instance when 'indexing' is in the first position in the array for your sample of data. rows with no match can be found with `WHERE NOT array[t.col1, t.col2, t.col3] && array['postgres', 'indexing', 'similarity']`

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple [inverted index](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index): Create and maintain (probably using triggers - an exercise for the reader), a table that stores the tag and the id of the source data, eg:

```
create table tag_mytable (
    tag text not null,
    mytable_id int not null references mytable,
    primary key (tag, mytable_id)
)
```

You can then very efficiently find mytable row tag hit count:

```
with hits as (
    select mytable_id
    from tag_mytable
    where tag = $1
    union all
    select mytable_id
    from tag_mytable
    where tag = $2
    union all
    select mytable_id
    from tag_mytable
    where tag = $3
), hits_total as (
    select mytable_id, count(*) as tag_hits
    from hits
    group by 1
)
select t.*
from mytable t
left join hits_total h on h.mytable_id = t.mytable_id
order by h.tag_hits
```

This has the added advantage of assigning a hit count of zero to rows without any hits (presumably most of them) without having to compare their data.

Consider bypassing storing the tags in mytable and instead store them only in this new table, which eliminates the need for triggers etc, and allows any number of tags per mytable (albeit with a minor tweak to the query).

Comment: Does the `tag_mytable` even need an `id serial`?

Comment: @Bergi not really. The actual primary key is `tag, mytable_id`, but if using a framework like hibernate I find it a pain to have to deal with the code noise of `@Embedded` keys. Actually, in this case I'll nuke id because a double barrelled key would provide a covering index.

Comment: Would this be slower than the option in the question if there are a small number of tags and many posts sharing the same tags? E.g. if a large number of posts have a given tag, then it would be grouping by a large number of ids. I'll try it on some sample data later

Comment: @Leo to answer questions of performance, it's best to do a practical test rather than theorize. I will say that this is scaleable. However, if scale is not an issue, I would go with the simpler solution even if the query is heavier.